# How does Blistering Dieflyn work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Blistering Dieflyn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blistering%20Dieflyn) gains +1/+0 when you use a swamp or mountain.

If you tap multiple mountains or swamps, can it be for example 5/1? Can you use multiple lands on it?

Answer (score 6):

First off, though most often you get your mana from lands, it's not "when you use a swamp or a mountain" but "when you pay a black or red mana".

And yes, you can activate the ability multiple times, for example paying 2 red and 2 black mana to give it a total of +4/+0.

This is called an activated ability, as is anything else of the form "[cost]: [effect]" (note the colon). You can activate an activated ability as many times as you want, as long as you can pay the cost. Sometimes their cost is tapping (for example [Cinderhaze Wretch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cinderhaze%20Wretch)), in which case since you can't tap something that's already tapped, you'll only be able to use the ability once at a time. But in this case, the cost is simply mana, which you can pay repeatedly.

Note that you are technically activating the ability multiple separate times, not just paying more for a bigger effect all at once. The difference doesn't usually matter, but in some cases it can be handy to do something in between activations.